# Access request context anywhere

Tags: node.js, express

I'm using Express and I need to access some data that it is on the request  (headers, cookies, etc) every time I use the log to debug and trace my app.

With other languages (ie: Java) I have the "Thread Context" where I can put that data, and so access it whenever I log something. But with NodeJS there is no such thing, as far as I know, because we have only one thread.

I'm trying to avoid passing the `req` variable in every function so I can log that info.

Is there a node or expressjs feature that let me get the data anywhere?

Comment: There are modules - but honestly implicit request-global variables are terrible and you should avoid them as much as you can. Only your route handler itself should access the request and then only pass relevant bits to the parts that need them.

Comment: @Amit it's a legitimate question - I guess it can be edited to be more legit by removing the part that says "is there are a module" and leave it at "is there an express or node feature"

Comment: Neuquino - see @BenjaminGruenbaum comment. Please edit your question.

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum I get your point, but it is also bad to add an extra argument to ALL my functions in order to access data that it is only relevant for logging

Comment: @Neuquino you're right, you should inject the logging function to the component that's in charge of logging - and then pass the logger around to functions that use it. If you don't want to pass it around to all objects - put them in classes and pass it to the class's constructor. This pattern (dependency injection) is universal in modern software design - you can use an injector to pass the logger automatically but explicitly. Uncontrolled global state is terrifying :)

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum Thread local variables in Java and C# are not "uncontrolled global state". 
They are local for each thread and when it comes to gathering state that is tied to a specific call-chain I cannot see how you can replace them with dependency injection as long as the program logic is made up by functions calling functions? There are use cases in which they are needed and libraries like Continuation Local Storage exist for a reason.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

**Update**: Node recently introduced this as a native feature:
`AsyncLocalStorage` is similar to thread-local storage in other languages.

https://nodejs.org/api/async_context.html

---

**Old answer**

Have a look at Continuation Local Storage, it implements something similar to thread context for asynchronous call chains: https://github.com/othiym23/node-continuation-local-storage

Also there are efforts to build asynchronous local storage as a standardized feature into javascript itself, but they are still at a very early stage: TC39 Zone Proposal https://docs.google.com/presentation/d/1H3E2ToJ8VHgZS8eS6bRv-vg5OksObj5wv6gyzJJwOK0

Comment: This should be flagged as the correct answer. The currently flagged correct answer does not answer the question correctly.

Comment: Be careful with this library though as it's buggy in my opinion. I tried it when was making multitenant app solution and this library was loosing contexts when I performed stress tests. I ended up passing request context in every function where I needed it. At first look it seems not cool, but explicit better than implicit in my opinion.

Answer (score 1):

[AsyncLocalStorage](https://nodejs.org/api/async_context.html#class-asynclocalstorage) maintains an independent storage context, this could be the way to access the request context in the subsequent functions as part of the request lifecycle (only if `req` is not passed to the asynchronous functions).

Here's a way to push values to the `AsyncLocalStorage`:

```
const asyncStorage = new AsyncLocalStorage();

const requestLoggerMiddleWare = (req, res, next) => {
  asyncStorage.run(new Map(), () => {
    asyncStorage.getStore().set('key', req.get('example-header'));
    next();
  });
};

app.use(requestLoggerMiddleWare)
```

This value can be consumed in any function until the asynchronous function call is resolved.

```
const exampleHeader = asyncStorage.getStore().get('example-header');
```

Answer (score -3):

The fact that JavaScript is single threaded is not a limitation and doesn't prevent using "Thread Context" as a means to use "universally accessible state". The problems will start as soon as asynchronous calls are made and the state no longer matches what you intend it to be.

This is one of the reasons why global state is considered "bad habit" and you should aim to avoid it (not specifically when developing in JavaScript and/or Node...).

Instead, you *should* pass around an object, but not `req`. You should construct your objects or call your functions in such a way that the `log` instance that's relevant to every call chain (starting at the request event and through all internal calls) is passed around. That `log` instance should be initialized with whatever context of required for logging, and in your case, the request details from the original `req`.

Comment: I don't think that adding an extra argument to ALL my functions in ALL my modules just for logging would be an elegant solution. I know it will not be as easy as `var log = require('myLog'); log.debug ('something')`. But I'm trying to achieve something like that.

Comment: Of course there are ways - the most trivial ones are: domains, zones, promise libraries that offer context with bind (like bluebird), fibers and so on.

Comment: @Neuquino which would cause tight code coupling, would make testing harder, would prevent you from changing your logging scheme (what if you want more context, but just `req`?) and won't even work as soon as multiple context's are needed simultaneously (via asynchronous code).

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum - (sorry was just rewriting the content so it's not out of order, but...) All your suggestions apply when a unique context object exists per "transaction" (request...), which is what my answer is about, but won't work with `require('myLog')` as suggest in Neuquino's comment.

Comment: @Amit care to touch on this a bit more? I'm interested in seeing how this is implemented.

Comment: @nikkwong - the format is not really suitable for code in this case. Can you be more specific? What would you like to know more about?

Comment: Nothing wrong with passing around a request context holding a small set of useful variables, such as log context.  Purist attitudes about that can wreak destruction on architectures.

Comment: @Blaze obviously you don't even understand my answer as it is exactly what you suggest in your comment. It's a shame you downvote without bothering to understand the post.

Comment: Maybe you should clarify that the user should be passing around a request context (as the OP asked for) rather than a "log" instance.  Passing around a log instance everywhere is a Bad Idea.  ALso, global state and TLS is fine when used correctly.   Just because Node doesn't support it doesn't mean its a bad idea.

Comment: To generalize that global state is a "bad habit" is hard to swallow. Would like to see some references for that. Most modern languages support it and use it at the infrastructure level. Just because JS doesn't support it doesn't make it bad.