# Is it possible to have "thread" local variables in Node?

Tags: node.js

I would like to store a variable that is shared between all stack frames (top down) in a call chain. Much like ThreadLocal in Java or C#.

I have found https://github.com/othiym23/node-continuation-local-storage but it keeps loosing context for all my use cases and it seems that you have to patch the libraries you are using to make it local-storage-aware which is more or less impossible for our code base.

Are there really not any other options available in Node? Could domains, stacktraces or something like that be used to get a handle (id) to the current call chain. If this is possible I can write my own thread-local implementation.

Comment: Adding a [MCVE] to this question would be a very useful thing. JS is single threaded, all variables you declare are technically thread-local (or less).

Comment: Please look up how thread-local variables work in Java, C# or even Python. This is a well established area and has nothing to do with placing ordinary variables on the stack.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thread-local_storage

Comment: I know what thread-local storage is. I'm saying that you should add a code sample that demonstrates your issue.

Comment: Which I won't do since the question is general.

Comment: @Joppe since there are not threads, tread-local storage doesn't make sense. Hence, an example of what you are trying to achieve, or a more elaborate question with specifics, would be helpful. Right now, your question has a faint whiff of XY problem.

Comment: Sure there are no threads per se in node, but there are still call-chains. What I am looking for is a way to tie variables to each such call chain. 

The library https://github.com/othiym23/node-continuation-local-storage (that I refered too) tries to accomplish this, but it does not really succeed with this task, so I am asking here to see if someone knows if the basic mechanism is available in node to accomplish this or not.

Comment: @robertklep The StrongLoop team seem to recognize my use case since they announced support for zones a few years ago (https://strongloop.com/strongblog/announcing-zones-for-node-js/) and part of that new concept was the "association of arbitrary data with asynchronous control flow".

Not much progress there implementation-wise (https://github.com/strongloop/zone), but TC39 (ECMAScript) seem to instead have picked it up making it an possible inherent part of future ES: https://docs.google.com/presentation/d/1H3E2ToJ8VHgZS8eS6bRv-vg5OksObj5wv6gyzJJwOK0/edit#slide=id.p.

Comment: @Joppe I'm not saying that aren't any use cases for this, it's just that I can probably think of half a dozen ways of achieving something like that (using class instances, promise binding, callback binding, partial callbacks, ...). It really depends on what the actual problem is that you're trying to solve.

Comment: @robertklep A similar use case to mine is described in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34556637/access-request-context-anywhere, so could you please show us how to solve this with either class instances, promise binding, callback binding or partial callbacks without passing around a variable? 

I think it is impossible, but I would love to be proved wrong.

Comment: @Joppe I would solve that question using Express middleware (again, the solution depends on the actual problem that has to be solved...)

Comment: @robertklep Could you please show us how?

Adding an extra middleware to extract data about the request and then injecting it into the request object is trivial. The problem starts when you want to use this extracted information further down the call-chain. 

I would say that you cannot avoid explicitly passing around this request object in every place where you want to use the information you extracted in the first place, but as I said before, I would love to be proved wrong.

Comment: @Joppe if you encapsulate your call chain within a class, you can always access the context object from its methods without having to pass it around as an explicit argument. If that's a suitable approach depends on the use case.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/104843/discussion-between-joppe-and-robertklep).

Comment: All of this has now been sorted out and apparently was the question I asked in the first place valid, since AsyncLocalStorage now has been added to the Node.js standard library.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Yes, it is possible. Thomas Watson has spoken about it at NodeConf Oslo 2016 in his [Instrumenting Node.js in Production](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nvHxA7dYw0w) ([alt.link](https://www.elastic.co/videos/instrumenting-node-js-in-production-by-thomas-watson)).

It uses [Node.js tracing - AsyncWrap](https://github.com/nodejs/diagnostics/tree/master/tracing/AsyncWrap) (which should eventually become a well-established part of the public Node API). You can see an example in the open-source [Opbeat Node agent](https://github.com/opbeat/opbeat-node) or, perhaps even better, [check out the talk slides and example code](https://github.com/watson/talks/tree/a30dbf599a61dfe820b293680b89815be9f16615/2016/06%20NodeConf%20Oslo).

Comment: @Joppe How did you get on with this? continuation-local-storage appears to be using this technique under the hood now since it relies on the async-listener module mentioned in the talk, which these days uses the asyncWrap facilities.

Comment: @Andy I actually gave up on this, since all the answers I initially received failed to answer the real question and instead told me to pass around a context object (admittidly in new ingenious ways). Haven't looked into to this since Jakub made this posting, but it sounds really promising if continuation-local-storage has changed the underlying technique to something more reliable. Maybe it's time to make another try.

Comment: Doesn't appear to have changed very much since Feb when you asked the question.

Comment: Then there's is still not a working solution and we will have to wait for TC39 to implement zones (if it will ever happen).

Comment: And now I have given up on node.js. For the network services we build, Go is a much better alternative.

Comment: The video link above is unavailable. Can you update the link which isn't broken? Thanks.

Answer (score 9):

Now that more than a year has passed since I originally asked this question, it finally looks like we have a working solution in the form of Async Hooks in Node.js 8.

https://nodejs.org/api/async_hooks.html

The API is still experimental, but even then it looks like there is already a fork of Continuation-Local-Storage that uses this new API internally.

https://www.npmjs.com/package/cls-hooked

**Update**
According to the comment below, AsyncLocalStorage now seems to be the supported way to do this:
https://nodejs.org/api/async_context.html#class-asynclocalstorage

Comment: As of Node 19.7.0 Async Hooks are still marked as experimental. However, [Async Local Storage](https://nodejs.org/api/async_context.html#class-asynclocalstorage) is recommended. Maybe you should update your answer?

Answer (score 3):

Node.js 20 supplies [AsyncLocalStorage](https://nodejs.org/api/async_context.html#class-asynclocalstorage) for context tracing.  It looks like even the experimental Hooks was not a good solution. If you need context for something other than tracing you should open an issue.

Answer (score 1):

> TLS is used in some places where ordinary, single-threaded programs would use global variables but where this would be inappropriate in multithreaded cases.

Since javascript does not have exposed threads, global variable is the *simplest* answer to your question, but using one is a bad practice.

You should instead use a closure: just wrap all your asynchronous calls into a function and define your variable there.

## Functions and callbacks created within closure

```
  (function() (
       var visibleToAll=0;

       functionWithCallback( params, function(err,result) {
          visibleToAll++;
          // ...
          anotherFunctionWithCallback( params, function(err,result) {
             visibleToAll++
             // ...
          });
       });

       functionReturningPromise(params).then(function(result) {
          visibleToAll++;
          // ...
       }).then(function(result) {
          visibleToAll++;
          // ...
       });
    ))();
```

## Functions created outside of closure

Should you require your variable to be visible inside functions not defined within request scope, you can create a context object instead and pass it to functions:

```
  (function c() (
       var ctx = { visibleToAll: 0 };

       functionWithCallback( params, ctx, function(err,result) {
          ctx.visibleToAll++;
          // ...
          anotherFunctionWithCallback( params, ctx, function(err,result) {
             ctx.visibleToAll++
             // ...
          });
       });

       functionReturningPromise(params,ctx).then(function(result) {
          ctx.visibleToAll++;
          // ...
       }).then(function(result) {
          ctx.visibleToAll++;
          // ...
       });
    ))();
```

Using approach above all of your functions called inside `c()` get reference to same `ctx` object, but different calls to `c()` have their own contexts. In typical use case, `c()` would be your request handler.

## Binding context to `this`

You could bind your context object to `this` in called functions by invoking them via `Function.prototype.call`:

```
functionWithCallback.call(ctx, ...)
```

...creating new function instance with `Function.prototype.bind`:

```
var boundFunctionWithCallback = functionWithCallback.bind(ctx)
```

...or using promise utility function like [bluebird's `.bind`](http://bluebirdjs.com/docs/api/promise.bind.html)

```
Promise.bind(ctx, functionReturningPromise(data) ).then( ... )
```

Any of these would make ctx available inside your function as `this`:

```
this.visibleToAll ++;
```

...however *it has no real advantage over passing context around* - your function still has to be aware of context passed via `this`, and you could accidentally pollute global object should you ever call function without context.

Comment: Please take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34556637/access-request-context-anywhere. He is basically trying to solve the same use case as me. 

Could you please illustrate how to apply your closure-based solution to this problem (i.e. not having to pass the request object to each method in the call chain)?

Comment: This doesn't allow `functionWithCallback` (and any of the other functions that aren't defined inside the IIFE) to access `visibleToAll`.

Comment: No and that is one of the reasons for why there actually is a use case for something similar to thread local variables in ES.

Comment: @robertklep good point, i have expanded my answer to cover this.

Comment: @Koder Thanks for the effort, but you are not answering the question I asked. 

You start by saying that I should use a closure and then you go about demonstrating yourself that this is not a viable approach (since you either have to keep all calls inside the closure or pass around the state in a parameter - binding is just parameter passing in disguise).

Comment: The question I asked was if there exists something like thread-local variables in node.js or a mechanism to get a unique identifier to the current call-chain and after doing some research on my own I will soon answer my own question for others to benefit.

Comment: @Joppe Perhaps I had misread your question. When you rephrased it this way answer boils down to: "Yes, but they won't work the way you expect". But I'm looking forward to fruits of your research. As side note - promise binding gets propagated to all next promises.