# Is there any way to get some sort of "context" for NodeJs async execution "threads"?

Tags: node.js, promise, async-await, es6-promise

When you have a NodeJS HTTP server written with async/await, it would be very nice to have a "context" available. For example:

```
httpServer.on('request', funcA);

async function funcA(req) {
    await funcB();
}

async function funcB(req) {
    await funcC();
}

async function funcC(req) {
   await someApi.call();
   // I want to access the original HTTP request here! And other notes I've gathered about
   // the request while processing it in funcA() and funcB().
}
```

Currently the only way I know of is to pass a context object as a parameter down into every function you call. This works, but your code gets littered with the `context` parameter EVERYWHERE. Literally every function you write needs to take it as a parameter and pass it on to every other function because someone somewhere might need it. And that's annoying.

It would be better if there was a function `getContext()` which can be called anywhere and will return the current context object. But I have no idea how I could make that and how to determine the current "request thread" if you can call it that.

Is there any way?

Comment: i really don't think its possible.`funcB` has no relation to `funcA` besides the call. And i'm pretty sure there is no equivalent of `ThreadLocal` like you could use in java

Comment: Actually, i am wrong: See this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35649998/is-it-possible-to-have-thread-local-variables-in-node and this: https://nodejs.org/api/async_hooks.html. Here is an actual example: https://stackabuse.com/using-async-hooks-for-request-context-handling-in-node-js/