# node js - session object

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

i've a very simple application in node/express that, once a user connects, runs a http to another server, do some computation on the received data and responds to the user.

now because the data flowing server-to-server and the computation required are the bottleneck of this flow, i don't want to redo this job for every user who connects to my app.

is there any way to do this http request and its successive computation only for the first user and then reuse that for every following user?

some code

```
var app = null;
router.get('/ask', function(req, res, next) {
...
dbService.select('apps',appId).then(function(data,err,  header){
    app = data.rows[0].doc;     

    app.a1.forEach(function(item, index){
      app.a1[index]['nameSpellchecker'] = new natural.Spellcheck(item.synonyms);
    });

    app.a1.forEach(function(item, index){
      app.a2[index]['nameSpellchecker'] = new natural.Spellcheck(item.synonyms);
    });

    ...
    res.status(200).send(JSON.stringify(response));
})
```

basically what i want to keep is the app object

thanks, Loris

Comment: can you share your code?

Comment: Also, How many concurrent users are you trying to target? What sort of computation is the user waiting for is it time sensitive information, for eg lets say 4 concurrent users connect to your server. assuming a queue is in place user1, user2, user3, user4, the computation will only happen for user1 and if the result of the computation will be shared between user2, user3, user4. Wont that give a stale data to the other users?

Comment: Let's Info are not time sensitive,i will address that later... I've found somenthing interesting here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19925857/global-scope-for-every-request-in-nodejs-express i want to share objs between requests not modules... Thanks guys!

Answer (score 0):

Create a variable in a shared scope.

When there is a connection, test to see if the variable has a value.

If it does not, assign to it a Promise that will resolve with the data you want.

Then add a `then` handler to get the data out of it and do what you want.

```js
var processed_data;

function get_processed_data() {
  if (processed_data) {
    return; // Already trying to get it
  }

  processed_data = new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
    // Replace this with the code to get the data and process it
    setTimeout(function() {
      resolve("This is the data");
    }, 1000);
  });

}

function on_connection() {
  get_processed_data();

  processed_data.then(function(data) {
    // Do stuff with data
    console.log(data);
  });
}

on_connection();
on_connection();
on_connection();
setTimeout(on_connection, 3000); // A late connection to show it still works even if the promise has resolved already
```

You then have a single promise responsible for fetching the data for each connection, and it will cache it for subsequent connections.